# Google Sheets conditional formatting based data validation drop down

Tags: google-sheets

Good afternoon.  I have a task of trying to setup a google sheet with QC checks with our equipment on site.  I have 5 columns with cells B6:F6 having a drop down with 4 separate options.

What this is for is the QC tech inputs a weight for that part producted every hour.  That weight would need to only be for the range that was chosen in the dropdown and not the other 3 options.

[snip of the document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pyya.png)

This is because the lines change the molds based on needs and are not always the same everyday.

So when a QC tech selects 90 Mil for line 7 and puts in 890 for the weight it would turn green however 891 would turn red.  I was able to do this part however if they were to select 20L I would need the cells below reset and to only turn green for 930 and red for anything greater or less than if that makes sense.

Any help would be appreciated

Link to the spreadsheet that ive been testing with

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a9yLHZM4OzOgLW5kfMloO9GHU76MCER0BD7btfsWXzs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow! Can you please share a sample/copy of your spreadsheet (link to your spreadsheet, not just snip) and your desired output. Remove sensitive data if any.

Comment: Ive attached it above.

Comment: From `when a QC tech selects 90 Mil for line 7 and puts in 890 for the weight it would turn green however 891 would turn red`. What is the basis of this condition? How will I know when to turn green and when to turn red? Please add these details. Also please clarify the part `That weight would need to only be for the range that was chosen in the dropdown and not the other 3 options.`

Comment: My apologies as I am new to google sheets and formulas. The goal is to have all 4 pail sizes as a drop down list which are 90 Mil, 20L, 70Mil, and 3.5G.

Each of these 4 pail sizes have a target weight of 90 Mil (890g), 20L (930g), 70Mil (725g), and 3.5G (720g) in grams.  The goal of this was be when I select one of the 4 options on row 6, the corresponding cells in the column would have conditional formatting for that weight.

Comment: On sheet one named Cell one you can see an example I did as these lines never change. I did conditional formatting for greater than, less than, and equal too the weight for 90 Mil.  I cant do this with Cell 3 however as what product is produced on each line changes every week.

The goal is for the user to select a pail size and have the conditional formatting change depending on the selection for the color coding and greater than, less than #s if that makes sense.

Comment: I am not sure if what you are trying to do is possible using only the conditional formatting. But from how I understood your question, I have posted an answer using apps script.

Answer (score 0):

### Suggestion using Apps Script:

**Try:**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var val = e.value;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var col = range.getColumn();

  var dropdownValue = sheet.getRange(6, col).getValue();

  if (row > 6 && col < 7) {
    if ((dropdownValue == "90 Mil" && val == "890") || (dropdownValue == "20L" && val == "930") || (dropdownValue == "70 Mil" && val == "725") || (dropdownValue == "3.5" && val == "720")) {
      sheet.getRange(row, col).setBackground("green")
    } else if (val == null) {
      sheet.getRange(row, col).setBackground("white")
    } else {
      sheet.getRange(row, col).setBackground("red")
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: Hope this helps! Let me know if you have questions/concern.

Comment: Apologies once again but I have app editor open on the sheet and attempted to save/run it I get the following error.  Is there a value or sheet name I need to change?

https://imgur.com/a/rm8vO9d

Comment: You can't run the onEdit trigger on the script editor since it is looking for the object e which is only created upon changing a value in the spreadsheet, just save it and try inputting values on your sheet. It runs automatically when a user changes a value in a spreadsheet. You may read the detailed description  here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

Comment: Thank you for all the help, I see it now.  

You have been a life saver on this project.

Comment: One final question, if I wanted the 90 Mil to be green between 890 and 910, how would I word that?  I see it in the script im just not 100% certain.

Im assuming it would have to be where "&& val == "890" is

Comment: Yup you can change it from `(dropdownValue == "90 Mil" && val == "890")` to `(dropdownValue == "90 Mil" && val >= 890 && val <= 890)`. Hope this solved your concern.